# My application uses 1GB of memory each 20 seconds

Tags: vb.net, memory, system.drawing

I have made a app which draws bitmaps(800x500) each 30 ms. And displays them in a picturebox also the parts in the drawn image are objects. This process uses 50MB each time it renders and I'm very worried.

This is the rendering code:

```
Public Function Draw() As Bitmap
    Dim b as New Bitmap(RenderWidth * Me.Camera.Zoom, RenderHeight * me.camera.zoom)
    Dim g = graphics.FromImage(b)
    For each i in me.elements
        Dim calculated as new point(i.location.x - me.camera.x, i.location.y - me.camera.x)
        Dim resized as new bitmap(i.Image, New Size(i.Image.Width * i.Scale, i.Image.Height * i.Scale))
        g.DrawImage(resized, caluculated)
    Next
    'camera zooming code
    Dim oldSize as size = b.Size
    Dim calculatedLoc = CalucLoc(oldSize, rendersize)
    b = b.Clone(New Rectangle(caluclatedLoc, RenderSize), b.Pixelformat)
    Return b
End Function
Function CalucLoc(bigSize, smallSize) as Point
    Dim result as new size
    Dim half_w1 = bigSize.Width / 2
    Dim half_h1 = bigSize.Height / 2
    Dim half_w2 = smallSize.Width / 2
    Dim half_h2 = smallSize.Height / 2
    Dim caluc_x = half_w1 - half_w2
    Dim caluc_y = half_h1 - half_h2
    result = New Point(caluc_x, caluc_y)
    return result
End Function
```

The element class doesn't do anything it just acts as a container of all the properties.

Comment: When and where do you free all those bitmaps you're creating? They take up memory, and if you keep taking it and never give any back, you're going to run out at some point. It also seems like you're leaking memory when you create a new bitmap and assign it to `b`, and then a few lines later throw it away in favor of a copy of something else with `b = b.clone()`. That means that until GC runs, you've temporarily got two copies of each `b` for every time you call `Draw()`.

Comment: `Bitmap` implements `IDisposable`, which is likely to mean that it has unmanaged resources that are liable to leak.  You should never use a `Bitmap` without either enclosing it in a `Using` block or ensuring that `Dispose` is called directly when you're done with it (most likely by calling `Dispose` within the `Dispose` of another object that implements `IDisposable`).

Comment: It's not just the Bitmaps you're creating, also the Graphics object needs to be disposed of. Just declare the Graphics object with a `Using` statement; **pre-calculate** the area of the Bitmap to render, so you don't need to build new Bitmaps in a loop, just define its size. Return that Bitmap object and, since you're showing it in a PictureBox, add `[Your PictureBox].Image?.Dispose() [Your PictureBox].Image = Draw()`. It's not clear what `elements` contains, why you're not passing this collection to the method and whether the objects it references also need to be disposed.

Comment: @Jimi There are no methods in the element class just the `new` method and I will try the `dispose()` method

Comment: Never said anything like it. `element` is a collection of objects (Images, from what you're showing), so you need to call `Dispose()` on each object that this collection references, if you're not reusing them: that's not clear, since you haven't described the use and origin of these Images. The important parts, for now are: 1) declare the Graphics object with a `Using` statement, 2) Dispose of the previous Bitmap you have assigned to the PictureBox before you assign a new one, as described: `[The PictureBox].Image?.Dispose() [The PictureBox].Image = Draw()` 3) Don't create Bitmaps in a loop.